# Result Type for Excel

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, managed-property

I'm having a problem with my Excel File Search Results. See image.

If my Excel file has a Title under File > Info > Properties the Title will show up correctly with the correct link to the file, however in most cases that Title is missing. I'm not having this problem with my PDF or Word documents.

I often end up with two results for the same Excel file, one with the file name but an added "~$" in front of the link making it a broken link.

And the second one has the icon and correct URL but no Title, therefore, making it not clickable.

I understand I can create a new custom Result Type for Excel files but I'm not clear on what those customizations should be in regards to the code, or using a different managed property.

This is an on-prem installation of Sharepoint 2013. I'm including two images. One showing my search results and one showing my prioritized crawled properties on Title.

(image removed)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Title is showed at the first line, after the File Type, more information about display template layout, refer to [it](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/use-result-types-and-display-templates).

If you want to show File Name, you can customize the display template. For this part, you can refer to [this article](https://switch2sharepoint.wordpress.com/2014/11/15/replace-document-titles-with-document-filenames-in-search-results-in-sharepoint-2013/).

In addition, you can also change the Title managed property to show File Name when Title is empty. At the mappings to crawled properties section, click "Add a mapping" to add ows_Name into the list, like the below:
[image]

Note: After changing the managed properties, you need to make sure a full crawl for your content source.

Comment: This linked article on changing the Display Template is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Also I discovered the files starting with ~$ are temporary files so nothing I can do about that.